# Possible to mount an NTFS partition with uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=022,fmask=133 but allow files to later be chmod'd?

Tags: permissions, mount, ntfs, chmod

This is for a single-user system that's using an NTFS partition as its $HOME; is it possible to mount the partition in such a way that

1. New files would be owned by $USER:$USER with 644 permission
2. New folders would be owned by $USER:$USER with 755 permission
3. Both files and folders can later be chmod'd ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but `ntfs-3g`, the driver that provides NTFS access on Linux, has a "User Mapping" feature that looks like it must be enabled with a `permissions` option.  You also need to map Linux users to Windows SIDs.  Read the [ntfs-3g](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-faq/#permissions) documentation for further information.